# Cannot load http-kit library in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, http-kit

I'm working on windows in eclipse counterclockwise. When i run this code:

```
(require 'http-kit)
;; start concurrent requests, get promise, half the waiting time

    (let [response1 (http-kit/get "https://clojure.org")
          response2 (http-kit/get "http://clojure.org/")]
      ;; Handle responses one-by-one, blocking as necessary
      ;; Other keys :headers :body :error :opts
      (println "response1's body: " (:body @response1))
      (println "response2's status: " (:status @response2)))
```

i got following message:

```
CompilerException java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate http_kit__init.class or http_kit.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name., compiling:(restful_clojure\test.clj:1:1)
```

so, next I run:

```
    (println (seq (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader))))
```

after which i get:

```
(#object[java.net.URL 0x50b65482 file:/E:/workspace/restful-clojure/test/] #object[java.net.URL 0x5f5d7651 file:/E:/workspace/restful-clojure/src/] #object[java.net.URL 0x2878624e file:/E:/workspace/restful-clojure/dev-resources] #object[java.net.URL 0xe56e16d file:/E:/workspace/restful-clojure/resources/] #object[java.net.URL 0x6c26a661 file:/E:/workspace/restful-clojure/target/classes/] #object[java.net.URL 0x58fdaa4a file:/C:/Users/Maciek/.m2/repository/clojure-complete/clojure-complete/0.2.3/clojure-complete-0.2.3.jar] #object[java.net.URL 0x337cc909 file:/C:/Users/Maciek/.m2/repository/http-kit/http-kit/2.1.19/http-kit-2.1.19.jar] #object[java.net.URL 0xa181b82 file:/C:/Users/Maciek/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar] #object[java.net.URL 0x53d4a10e file:/C:/Users/Maciek/.m2/repository/ccw/ccw.server/0.2.0/ccw.server-0.2.0.jar] #object[java.net.URL 0x664eeec4 file:/C:/Users/Maciek/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.10/tools.nrepl-0.2.10.jar] #object[java.net.URL 0x33af4785 
file:/C:/Users/Maciek/.m2/repository/org/tcrawley/dynapath/0.2.3/dynapath-0.2.3.jar] #object[java.net.URL 0x79a18e79 file:/C:/Users/Maciek/.m2/repository/cider/cider-nrepl/0.9.0/cider-nrepl-0.9.0.jar] #object[java.net.URL 0xf0b9c92 file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_51/src.zip] #object[java.net.URL 0x1ea27b79 file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_51/lib/tools.jar])
```

and as you can see http-kit is loaded

```
 #object[java.net.URL 0x337cc909 file:/C:/Users/Maciek/.m2/repository/http-kit/http-kit/2.1.19/http-kit-2.1.19.jar]
```

what is strange is that it worked fine before last system restart.

Here is my project.clj

```
    ;(defproject restful-clojure "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    ;  :description "FIXME: write description"
    ;  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
    ;  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
    ;            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
    ;  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]])
    ; project.clj
    (defproject restful-clojure "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
      ; ...project settings...

      ; The :dependencies key maps to a vector containing all dependencies
      ; necessary for our project. The dependency on Clojure itself should
      ; have already been added by Leiningen. We will add Ring, the Jetty
      ; adapter (so we can start up a web server to serve our application),
      ; and Compojure, which we will use later on in this tutorial.
      :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                     [http-kit "2.1.19"]])
```

Comment: fix your require as follows: `(require '[org.httpkit.client :as http-kit])` (http://www.http-kit.org/client.html)

Comment: thank you, you saved my day

Comment: @OlegTheCat Copy this comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the answer to the question, but it's related and I found this question while trying to solve my error, so I think this might help other people.

I got the same error as the OP because I forgot to add

```
[http-kit "2.2.0"]
```

inside `:dependencies []` in project.clj.

The OP had the dependency line correct, but wasn't aliasing it when calling `(require)`. The actual answer to the OP's question is in a comment which so far hasn't been turned into an answer yet.